# sql GROUP within group

Tags: sql, group-by

Let's say I have this database:

```
ID  | Name   | City  
1   | John   | TLV
2   | Abe    | JLM
3   | John   | JLM
```

I want to know how many people with different names are in each city.
I tried to use `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT `city`, count(`index`) as `num` FROM `people`
GROUP BY `city`, `name`
```

But this seems to group by *both*.

```
City  | num
TLV   | 1
JLM   | 1
```

What I want to do is to group by `city`, and group the results by `name`.

```
City  | num
TLV   | 1
JLM   | 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT `city`, count(distinct name) as `num`
FROM `people`
GROUP BY `city`;
```

You might want just `count(name)` . . . I'm not sure what you mean by "differently named".  `count(name)` is preferable, if you don't need the `distinct`.